# Pass an asterisk as part of a string in a command line argument into a python program?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a script that (in turn) calls a command line program. It would vastly simplify my life if there was a way that it could accept a command of the form

```
psfcheck.py -n file*.img
```

in a way such that within the program I could then use the term "file*.img" as a string, since there are a few times I want to pass such a string through other command line programs which need to be run on the batch of files as a group (not individually, one at a time).

Is this possible? It feels like a n00bish question, but I've been pythoning for a while and have never stumbled across this.

Comment: It's not a Python question so much as a shell question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell will expand any wildcards that it finds. You can prevent this by putting them inside quotes to hide them from the shell:

```
psfcheck.py -n "file*.img"
```

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around the argument:

```
psfcheck.py -n "file*.img"
```

That will prevent the shell from expanding the pattern into the list of matching files.